# Internet Explorer sometimes won't render SVG background images when those are changed with JS

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, background-image

In our application we recently changed all icons to SVG format. Of course, many buttons can be disabled/enabled, so we need to swap icons. When the icons were PNG, previously, this worked without problems on all browsers.
However, with SVG, this *sometimes* doesn't work on Internet Explorer.

After many tries, we figured that the problem appears to be this: *when you change `background-image` on an element to some SVG image that is already cached by the browser, IE will sometimes not render it*. In other words, when you change SVG background, on IE it *sometimes* effectively becomes "no background". In DOM it is there, i.e. can be retrieved without problems using JavaScript or browser's F12 console, just not rendered.

The only 100% working workaround we could come up with is to append '?###'  to image URL, where '###' is some random number. This forces IE to bypass the cache and thus its bug is never triggered. However, this is of course very bad for traffic, leads to flickering and has other downsides.

Does anyone know a good workaround for this bug in IE?